# How do I determine the direction of a wave?

Tags: waves

The solution of the wave equation,
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi(x,t)$$
by separation of variables is
$$\psi(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}+Be^{i(kx+\omega t)}+Ce^{-i(kx+\omega t)}+De^{-i(kx-\omega t)} \, .$$
I know that we a function with the form:$f(kx-\omega t)$ indicates a wave moving forward, and a function of the form:$f(kx+\omega t)$ indicates a wave moving backward. However, in the solution
$$\psi(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}+Be^{i(kx+\omega t)}+Ce^{-i(kx+\omega t)}+De^{-i(kx-\omega t)} \, ,$$
there are two terms with the form $f(kx-\omega t)$:
$$Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} \quad \text{and} \quad De^{-i(kx-\omega t)} \, .$$ What is the difference between them?

Comment: Look at it this way, your function has two independent variables $x$ and $t$. So your function $\phi(x,t)$ has a 2D basis. The 2D basis results in 4 co-ordinate quadrants. each of the terms $\pm kx \pm \omega t$ occupies one of the four quadrants

Comment: @ubuntu_noob Quite right. Would you be willing to expand that thought into an answer?

Comment: @DanielSank Yeah yeah doing it below. Thanks for making me less lazy btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the initial and boundary conditions. The solution,

$$\psi(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} +Be^{i(kx+\omega t)} + Ce^{-i(kx+\omega t)} +De^{-i(kx-\omega t)}$$

is the general solution of the wave equation and thus carries no particular direction. It is possible to have a wave function that travels both to the left and to the right such as:

$$\psi(x,t) = Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)} + Be^{i(kx+\omega t)}  $$

Which can create a stationary wave in some cases (e.g. if $A=B$). If one specifies initial conditions such that

$$\psi(x,t)= A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$

then one has a wave that moves forward expicitly.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why the directionality is not obvious to you is because you are solving a 1-dimensional case. For instance, if you were to write your answer in 3D, you would get:

$\psi(\pmb r, t) = A e^{i(\pmb k \cdot \pmb r - \omega t)} + C. C.$

The initial choice of the coordinate system with respect to the geometry of the problem defines the sign of the scalar product $\pmb k \cdot \pmb r = |\pmb k| |\pmb r| \cos \phi_{kr}$, where in case with co-aligned $\pmb k$ and $\pmb r$ the cosine will end up being $\pm1$ defining the relative propagation direction of the wave.

One other directional phase component is $\omega t$, where angular frequency $\omega$, by convention, is always positive. Hence, by choosing $\pm t$ you define the direction of time flow.